# SQL Server Import and Export wizard gives invalid object error on stored procedure with temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a stored proc that creates a temp table, inserts, selects then drops. Executing the stored proc within SQL Server Management Studio works fine and gives the expected result.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_TempTableTest
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @color VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmptable (
        color VARCHAR(10)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmptable (color) VALUES (@color)

    SELECT color FROM #tmptable

    DROP TABLE #tmptable

END
GO
```

However, when creating in the Import/Export tool and using that stored proc as the data source, it gives me the error:

> *Invalid object name '#tmptable'.*

Any idea why this would happen? If I change it to a table variable it seems work fine with Import/Export, but I don't understand why it is not working with a temp table.

Comment: Is there a way that you could try this without the DROP TABLE command?  When you wrote that it worked with a table variable, it seems like it doesn't find the table because it's removed.  If you remove the DROP TABLE and it works, the DROP TABLE command is the problem.  If it still doesn't work, something else might be causing the error.

Comment: I tried removing drop table from the sp completely, and still returns the invalid object error for the temp table when running through the Import/Export tool. It is very strange that the sp works fine when executed in SQL studio, but dies in the export job. This one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

When I run a mimicked stored procedure, like yours above, in SSMS, I can get the data returned like you mentioned in the procedure.  However, if I try the `#tmptable`, like you did, I also get the same error because the `DROP TABLE` removes it.  From what I can tell, the import/export is basically a final `INSERT` process.  The reason it works with the table variable is because the data still exist on the final insert; in the case of the `DROP TABLE`, it does not.  For instance, when I remove the `DROP TABLE`, it works.

I might be wrong here, but it seems the logic when it's an import or export in the case of the above procedure is

`INSERT` data

`SELECT` data

`DROP` data

`INSERT` (import/export): this generates the "Invalid object name tmptable'"

With the variable (or no `DROP`), it's

`INSERT` data

`SELECT` data

`INSERT` (import/export)

In the second case, the data still exist.  In the first case, they're gone.  One way around it if you want to use the #tmptable, start your code with:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmptable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmptable
```

Answer (score 0):

Put "SET FMTONLY OFF;" right above "SET NOCOUNT ON"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx